# "Originate in" or "originate from"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Tell me please which preposition I have to use after the word *originate* in the following sentence.

> I know what this phrase means, but it difficult to tell where it originates **in**/**from**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both prepositions are acceptable in a main clause:

X originated in Y

X originated from Y

> The spark that set the stable on fire originated from a smokestack nearby.
>
> These species originated in the sea but migrated into fresh water.

With respect your use in the *where*-clause,  I would say:

> I know what this phrase means, but it is difficult to tell where it originated.

You really don't need a preposition there, but if you are going to use one, use **from**, as user3169 pointed out in the comment below:

... You cannot tell from where it originated <sup>yes</sup>

... You cannot tell in where it originated <sup>no</sup>

So:

You cannot tell where it originated from.

Comment: Hmm... I would use *from* since you can also write "it is difficult to tell *from* where it originates". You can't use *in* this way.

Comment: @user3169: Right you are. I was thinking of **X originates in Y** and **X originates from Y**  in isolation, not in the context of this particular sentence with its *where*-clause.  I wouldn't use a preposition with the *where*-clause in any case.  I will edit the answer.